# How do I change the evisceration settings for debugging output in CCL?

Tags: common-lisp, ccl

When debugging in CCL, how do I change the uneviscerate the results of debugging calls like `(:raw 3)` and `(:v 5 3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does it:

```
(setq ccl::*BACKTRACE-PRINT-LENGTH* nil ccl::*BACKTRACE-PRINT-LEVEL* nil)
```